# ¿Cómo cambiar la forma de la figura de los botones de imagen del carousel?

Tags: bootstrap

tengo una pregunta, ¿es posible cambiar la forma de los botones de navegación del carousel de bootstrap? Estoy usando como base el carousel por defecto de bootstrap y pues tiene los botones cuadrados y quiero ver si es posible cambiar la forma a un circulo

Comment: El carrusel de Bootstrap tiene como botones dos signos de ángulo como < y >. Esos símbolos los porne mediante reglas CSS:
.carousel-control-next-icon  y .carousel-control-prev-icon    a las que les pone como background-image  las imágenes de los botones. Por defecto son dos definiciones tipo svg.

Answer (score 1):

Vale lo he comprobado y puedes sobreescribir las reglas CSS relativas a los botones

```
<style>
.carousel-control-next-icon{background-image: url("../images/flder.png"); }
.carousel-control-prev-icon{background-image: url("../images/flizq.png"); }
</style>
```

Como es lógico debes poner el origen de la imagen (url) en la url de tus imágenes.
Y esta definición debe ir después de cargar el archivo CSS de Bootstrap para sobre escribir la regla.
**Edito para los indicadores inferiores**
Para los indicadores inferiores también se puede actuar mediante CSS.Están construídos con una lista ordenada (ol) con la clase .carousel-indicators, los elementos de esta lista (li) pueden ponerse como círculos sobreescribiendo la clase de Bootstrap. Quedaría como

```
<style>
.carousel-indicators li{width:10px; height:10px;  border-radius: 50%;}
</style>
```

Igual que antes: se debe declarar después de cargar Bootstrap. El ancho y alto queda a tu elección, he puesto 10px, pero lógicamente tu elijes algo que quede proporcionado.
Incluso así puedes cambiarle el aspecto también en cuanto a colores por ejemplo.
Espero que te sea útil

Comment: Bueno, en realidad me refería a los que se encuentran debajo de las imágenes, no a las flechas de siguiente y anterior